# How to enable downloadify in jsPdf?

Tags: jspdf, html-to-pdf, downloadify

Hey I have added jsPdf into my HTML to download the HTML as a PDF, but in IE 9 it doesn't works. It is not downloading any PDF so I searched about this and got the I have to enable the IE shim for this so can you help me out that how I can be able to do that, I have tried to use Downloadify but didn't understand how to pass full HTML file and get the image of that into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps, but the support for downloadify is poor.

Add these script tags to the top of your page (changing the path as appropriate to the files in the lib directory of jspdf):

    `<script src="./js/jspdf/libs/Downloadify/js/downloadify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jspdf/libs/Downloadify/js/swfobject.js"></script>`

add a `<div id="downloadify">` in your dom. This div should be empty.

Next, add a script tag to the bottom of your page that will run after the DOM has been populated. This script will generate a button in the '#downloadify' div. Put this inside of the script tag:

```
Downloadify.create('downloadify',{ // this first argument id a dom element id. this is how it knows where to populate the flash button it's creating.
                    filename: "afilename.pdf",
                    data: function(){ 
                        // generate your pdf here.
                           var pdf = new jsPDF;
                        // various other jspdf commands here
                        return pdf.output();
                    },
                    onComplete: function(){ 
                        alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); 
                    },
                    onCancel: function(){ 
                        alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.');
                    },
                    onError: function(){ 
                        alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); 
                    },
                    swf: './js/jspdf/libs/Downloadify/media/downloadify.swf', // make sure this links properly to your file as well.
                    downloadImage: './js/jspdf/libs/Downloadify/images/download.png', // this is the link to the image of the button itself. An ugly default is included. If you want to style the button, you have to create a sprite image of the same kind.
                    width: 100, // width of the button
                    height: 30, // 1/4 height of the button image (which has four states present)
                    transparent: true, // seems to do nothing, set to true or false.
                    append: false // have not figured out what this does.
                });
```